# Best Drupal layout techniques

Tags: drupal, layout, drupal-theming

How do You define the layout of Your Drupal sites?
Which techniques do You find most useful?

I'm quite old-school and stick to templating.
It's true that I haven't practices the others too much. Yet, I'm also afraid that HTML output from Panels, Fusion or other fancy helpers would be twice as big as reasonably customised [Zen](http://drupal.org/project/zen).
Such techniques, however, probably reduce development time.

What do You think about these "clickable" solutions?

Comment: Should be CW as this is unanswerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [playing with template files tpl.php](http://drupal.org/node/341628)
- [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels)
- [Fusion](http://drupal.org/project/fusion) + [Skinr](http://drupal.org/project/skinr)
- [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds)

Some articles to the topic

- [Assembling Pages with Drupal - Blocks vs. Context vs. Panels](http://lullabot.com/articles/assembling-pages-with-drupal) on Lullabot
- [dynamic page layout in Drupal](http://groups.drupal.org/node/59378) on Drupal Groups
- [Display Suite vs Panels](http://www.jyvesgarden.com/blog/display-suite-vs-panels) by Jan-Yves Vanhaverbeke

Answer (score 0):

When you talk about Panels and Context which you didn't mention, they are much more than simple clicky layout tools. They can be used as such, but if you only want to setup layout you shouldn't use those two. That is not what they are meant for. These modules are used to create rules for how and what to display given the context of something, fx a node, a term or something else.

Comment: By layout I mean the whole layout system regarding contexts and different places - generally most of the things that You can also do with templating system